# How is this line returning the length of the array in recursion?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, recursion, array-algorithms

I am trying to understand this recursion using the debugger and trying to understand it step by step the main.The debugger shows the `smallAns` returns the size of the array I can't understand how this smallAns is returning the size of the array `input[]`.can anyone explain this

```
 #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int subsequences(char input[], int startIndex,char output[][50]){
          if(input[startIndex] == '\0'){
            output[0][0] = '\0';
            return 1;
          }
          int smallAns = subsequences(input, startIndex+1, output);
          for(int i = smallAns; i < 2*smallAns; i++){
            int row = i - smallAns;
            output[i][0] = input[startIndex];
            int j = 0;
            for(; output[row][j] != '\0'; j++){
                output[i][j + 1] = output[row][j];
            }
            output[i][j + 1] = '\0';
          }
          return 2*smallAns;
        }
        int main(){

      char input[] = "abc";
      char output[100][50];
      int ans = subsequences(input, 0, output);
      for(int i = 0; i < ans; i++){
        for(int j = 0; output[i][j] != '\0'; j++){
          cout << output[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
      }
    }
```

[image: recursion]

[image: watchvalue]

Comment: @ruakh edited the code

Comment: please give any valuable suggestion before down voting

Comment: `smallAns` is two to the power of the length of the input. I don't know why your debugger says differently; I'd guess that either you're looking at the variable before it's set (so you're seeing garbage) or you didn't make `output` big enough (so you're smashing the stack and then seeing garbage).

Comment: @ruakh `snallAns` returns the length of the array here i have taken input as `mickymouse` then it returns `10` ,I have tried other strings also and it gives the length of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the algorithm is doing:

Start at the end, with the empty subsequence (or "\0"). You have 1 subsequence.

Look at the last character not yet considered. For all the subsequences you have found, you can either add this last character, or don't. Therefore you have doubled the number of subsequences.

Repeat.

Therefore, 2 * smallAns means "Take the number of subsequences found in the lower recursive call, and double it."  And this makes sense after you know how it was implemented. Thus the importance of comments and documentation in code. :)